# How to convert a associative array into a string using implode function

Tags: php, arrays, implode

This is my associative array .

```
Array ( [month] => June [sale] => 98765 ) 
Array ( [month] => May [sale] => 45678 ) 
Array ( [month] => April [sale] => 213456 ) 
Array ( [month] => August [sale] => 23456 ) 
Array ( [month] => July [sale] => 12376 )
```

I want to convert it into two strings, like this
`["June", "May", "April", "August", "july"]`

and another one like this 
`[98765 , 45678 , 213456 , 23456 , 12376 ]`

I have used Implode function but I think I am missing something. Can anybody please help ?

Comment: you mean 2 new arrays right?

Comment: Two strings .
"June", "May", "April", "August", "july"
98765 , 45678 , 213456 , 23456 , 12376

Comment: @NishankMagoo please mark the right answer. the one you marked as an answer to your question will not work at all.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can simply do this by doing:

```
$strMonth = implode(', ', $arrVarName['month']);
$strSale = implode(', ', $arrVarName['sale']);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This wont work as it's multi-dimensional, you have to use `array_column`  Like this `[0=>['month'=>'June','sale'=>98765],1=>[...]]`, I suppose you could do it with a loop too, but why bother.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I suppose Nishank said Associative array! If multi-dimensional then  sure you have to use array_column() and then implode it into string.

Comment: "_I suppose you could do it with a loop too, but why bother._" @ArtisticPhoenix [Because using a single loop to populate two arrays cuts the time complexity in half.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72232194/2943403)

Answer (score 7):

Simple,Use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):-

```
$month_array = array_column($array,'month');
$sale_array = array_column($array,'sale');
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/ancBB

***Note:- If you want them as strings then do like below:-***

```
echo implode(',',array_column($array,'month'));

echo implode(',',array_column($array,'sale'));
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/F17AP

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the following code:-

```
$arr['month'] = array('June','July'); 

$arr['sale'] = array('123','234'); 

$strMonth = '["'.(implode('","', $arr['month'])).'"]';


$strSale = '['.(implode(', ', $arr['sale'])).']';


print_r($strMonth );

print_r($strSale );
```

And Output:-

```
["June","July"]
[123, 234]
```

Comment: I dont think so its wrost. I just give output as he wants. And don't judge me @Alive . Thanks

Comment: You have misrepresented the asker's input array structure.

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively asking for array columns to be json_encoded.

To improve efficiency, use a `foreach()` to populate both arrays in one pass.  This has half the time complexity of making two separate `array_column()` calls. I'll use a body-less loop with destructuring syntax for fun.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jOP7u))

```
$array = [
    ['month' => 'June', 'sale' => 98765],
    ['month' => 'May', 'sale' => 45678],
    ['month' => 'April', 'sale' => 213456],
    ['month' => 'August', 'sale' => 23456],
    ['month' => 'July', 'sale' => 12376],
];

$months = [];
$sales = [];
foreach ($array as ['month' => $months[], 'sale' => $sales[]]);
echo json_encode($months);
echo "\n---\n";
echo json_encode($sales);
```

Output:

```
["June","May","April","August","July"]
---
[98765,45678,213456,23456,12376]
```